# How to make fbox around minipage fit the whole minipage inside it?

Tags: minipage, framed

I have long equation, `Ax=b` that I want to put a frame around. I can't use `mdframed` since I need to also compile this with tex4ht, which still does not support `mdframed`. So I use this trick setup:

```
\fbox{
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\scriptsize
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
...
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{minipage}
}
\normalsize
```

This works, but the problem with the above, is that the fbox does not fit the whole `minipage`. Here is screen

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Without minipage and no frame, here is how it looks like:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

My question is: How can one automatically have `fbox` fit the minipage content? The solution has to also compile with not errors with `tex4ht`. Is there a way to tell Latex to shift the page margin to the left more, just in the minipage? i.e. make the minipage uses custom `geometry`?  I tried this

```
\fbox{
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\newgeometry{left=.1in,right=.1in,top=1in,bottom=1in}
\scriptsize
....
```

But it made things worst. 
I do get these messages from lualatex, but this is because the equations are too wide. But they are still in the page.

```
Overfull \hbox (31.09998pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 49--51
[][][]
```

Here is the MWE. Sorry for large equation size, but this is the example am working on.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}%
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage[paperheight=11in,paperwidth=8.5in,top=.7in,bottom=.7in, 
      left=1.2in, right=.8in]{geometry}
\begin{document}

Therefore, the $Ax=b$ system to solve is%

\fbox{
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\scriptsize
\[%
\begin{bmatrix}
7 & \left(  -4-\frac{1}{2}h^{3}\right)   & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\left(  -4+\frac{1}{2}h^{3}\right)   & 6 & \left(  -4-\frac{1}{2}h^{3}\right)
& 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
1 & \left(  -4+\frac{1}{2}h^{3}\right)   & 6 & \left(  -4-\frac{1}{2}%
h^{3}\right)   & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
0 & 1 & \left(  -4+\frac{1}{2}h^{3}\right)   & 6 & \left(  -4+\frac{1}{2}%
h^{3}\right)   & 1 & 0 & \cdots\\
0 & 0 & \left(  -4+\frac{1}{2}h^{3}\right)   & 6 & \left(  -4+\frac{1}{2}%
h^{3}\right)   & 1 & 0 & \cdots\\
&  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
&  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
&  &  &  &  &  &  &
\end{bmatrix}%
\begin{bmatrix}
y_{1}\\
y_{2}\\
y_{3}\\
y_{4}\\
\vdots\\
y_{N-2}\\
y_{N-1}\\
y_{N}%
\end{bmatrix}
=%
\begin{bmatrix}
h^{4}e^{h}-2hy_{0}^{\prime}+y_{0}\left(  4-\frac{1}{2}h^{3}\right)  \\
h^{4}e^{2h}-y_{0}\\
h^{4}e^{3h}\\
h^{4}e^{4h}\\
\vdots\\
\\
\\
\end{bmatrix}
\]
\end{minipage}
}
\normalsize

Therefore ...

\end{document}
```

compiled using `lualatex foo.tex` TL 2015

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to avoid `minipage`, that constrains the size.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage[
  letterpaper,
  top=.7in, bottom=.7in, 
  left=1.2in, right=.8in
]{geometry}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\paren}{(}{)}

\begin{document}

Therefore, the $Ax=b$ system to solve is
\[
\makebox[\textwidth]{\fbox{%
  \scriptsize$
  \begin{bmatrix}
  7 & \paren*{-4-\frac{1}{2}h^{3}}   & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
  \paren*{-4+\frac{1}{2}h^{3}}   & 6 & \paren*{-4-\frac{1}{2}h^{3}}
  & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
  1 & \paren*{-4+\frac{1}{2}h^{3}}   & 6 & \paren*{-4-\frac{1}{2}h^{3}}   & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
  0 & 1 & \paren*{-4+\frac{1}{2}h^{3}}   & 6 & \paren*{-4+\frac{1}{2}h^{3}}   & 1 & 0 & \cdots\\
  0 & 0 & \paren*{-4+\frac{1}{2}h^{3}}   & 6 & \paren*{-4+\frac{1}{2}h^{3}}   & 1 & 0 & \cdots\\
  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
  &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
  &  &  &  &  &  &  &
  \end{bmatrix}
  \begin{bmatrix}
  y_{1}\\
  y_{2}\\
  y_{3}\\
  y_{4}\\
  \vdots\\
  y_{N-2}\\
  y_{N-1}\\
  y_{N}
  \end{bmatrix}
  =
  \begin{bmatrix}
  h^{4}e^{h}-2hy_{0}^{\prime}+y_{0}\paren*{4-\frac{1}{2}h^{3}}  \\
  h^{4}e^{2h}-y_{0}\\
  h^{4}e^{3h}\\
  h^{4}e^{4h}\\
  \vdots\\
  \\
  \\
  \end{bmatrix}
$}}
\]
Therefore ...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You have

```
\fbox{
\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
\end{minipage}
}
```

`\fbox` like `\mbox` is a horizontal mode construct so `\noindent` there is not doing anything.

So you have on a line that is `\linewidth` wide

- A paragraph indent
- A vertical rule of width `\fboxrule`
- Padding of width `\fboxsep`
- one inter-word space from the white space after `{`
- A minipage of width `\linewidth`
- One inter-word space from the white space before `}`
- Padding of width `fboxsep`
- A vertical rule of width `\fboxrule`
- `\parfillskip` glue, natural length 0pt most likely.

That does not fit.

You want

```
\noindent
\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}
\end{minipage}%
}
```

Comment: the actual question is not clear, but it seems the OP has an issue with the fact that the actual contents of the minipage do not fit in `\linewidth`. He probably misunderstands the meaning of the minipage first argument.

Comment: Thanks. But on the question of `\noindent` it did change things. In one of my trials. I had this: `\fbox{ \noindent\begin{minipage}{\paperwidth}...` and now removing the `\noindent` made things worst, it shifted the minipage. But this only when using `\paperwidth`. If I had `\fbox{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}...` then, you are correct, now it has no effect. Removing it changes nothing. But before I was using `\paperwidth`, that is why I had it there. (too many variables, and too many options to tweak. Latex is hard!

Comment: @jfbu yes I spotted that as well but thought best to answer the general question in the title rather than the specifics about the particular content of this box.

Comment: @Nasser no `\noindent` inside the \fbox has _no effect_ it does not make it worse or better (and obviously it isn't affected by `\paperwidth` or `\linewidth`). tweaking latex isn't hard if you just follow some basic principles.

Answer (score 1):

Resize it to `\linewidth`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[
  letterpaper,
  top=.7in, bottom=.7in, 
  left=1.2in, right=.8in
]{geometry}    
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\paren}{(}{)}

\begin{document}

Therefore, the $Ax=b$ system to solve is
\[
\fbox{\resizebox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxrule-2\fboxsep}{!}{$
        \begin{bmatrix}
        7 & \paren*{-4-\frac{1}{2}h^{3}}   & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
        \paren*{-4+\frac{1}{2}h^{3}}   & 6 & \paren*{-4-\frac{1}{2}h^{3}}
        & 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0\\
        1 & \paren*{-4+\frac{1}{2}h^{3}}   & 6 & \paren*{-4-\frac{1}{2}h^{3}}   & 1 & 
        0 & \cdots & 0\\
        0 & 1 & \paren*{-4+\frac{1}{2}h^{3}}   & 6 & \paren*{-4+\frac{1}{2}h^{3}}   & 
        1 & 0 & \cdots\\
        0 & 0 & \paren*{-4+\frac{1}{2}h^{3}}   & 6 & \paren*{-4+\frac{1}{2}h^{3}}   & 
        1 & 0 & \cdots\\
        &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
        &  &  &  &  &  &  & \\
        &  &  &  &  &  &  &
        \end{bmatrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
        y_{1}\\
        y_{2}\\
        y_{3}\\
        y_{4}\\
        \vdots\\
        y_{N-2}\\
        y_{N-1}\\
        y_{N}
        \end{bmatrix}
        =
        \begin{bmatrix}
        h^{4}e^{h}-2hy_{0}^{\prime}+y_{0}\paren*{4-\frac{1}{2}h^{3}}  \\
        h^{4}e^{2h}-y_{0}\\
        h^{4}e^{3h}\\
        h^{4}e^{4h}\\
        \vdots\\
        \\
        \\
        \end{bmatrix}
        $}}
\]
Therefore \ldots\hrulefill
```

\end{document}

[image]